# Using special characters in bash associative array keys

Tags: arrays, linux, bash, console

I try to create an associative array in bash v4. The keys should be the names of directories and the value an ID. The problem is, that some directories contain special characters like parenthesis which leads to a syntax error.

My code is:

```
for PAGE in ${MOIN_PAGES[@]}
do
    CURRENT=`cat  $MOIN_DIRECTORY/data/pages/$PAGE/current`
    if [[ $CURRENT != cat* ]]
    then
        echo $CURRENT
        MOIN_REVISIONS["$PAGE"]=$CURRENT
    fi
done
```

Bash tells me, the error is in the line with

```
MOIN_REVISIONS["$PAGE"]=$CURRENT
```

MOIN_PAGES contains strings like "Abk(c3bc)rzungen"

Any ideas how to solve this?

Comment: You must declare an associative array before use. Use `declare -A MOIN_REVISIONS`. Else its just a normal indexed array.

Comment: `man bash` says "associative arrays are referenced using **arbitrary strings**" (my emphasis), so you should not get an error. Which error are you seeing?

Comment: The error message is:
/script.sh: line 26: Abk(c3bc)rzungen: syntax error in expression (error token is "(c3bc)rzungen")

Comment: You need to quote the expansion of `$PAGE` when you set `CURRENT`.

Comment: @Vivek thank you, that's the solution to my problem!

Comment: It appears that in recent Bash (tested on version 4.3.42(1)-release), the example key doesn't need to be quoted. `declare -A MOIN_REVISIONS;                                 PAGE="Abk(c3bc)rzungen"; CURRENT="dog"; MOIN_REVISIONS[$PAGE]=$CURRENT` gives no error, and `echo ${MOIN_REVISIONS[$PAGE]}` outputs "dog" as expected. Of course, quoting doesn't hurt.